# Is there a misnegation in the following example?

Tags: double-negation

I have a question about an excerpt that I read online. Here it is:

> Having reviewed the posts that you have identified, I conclude that you do not have any non-frivolous defamation against any of the posters.

My doubt is related to the second clause: "do not have any non-frivolous..." Is this a case of misnegation, in which the actual meaning of the phrase is "do not have any frivolous"?

Comment: In terms of language rather than law, we cannot know from your example whether the double negation is intended. It's like asking if "I don't know" should really be "I do know."  The answer is that it could be either.

Comment: It's a little weird, but the way I read it is that "you" does not have any "defamation" that is not frivolous -- ie, all of the "defamation" is frivolous.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Exactly, that was the reason why I had my doubt. But, after reading the answers and knowing how the use of language in law might be pedantic, I concluded there is no misnegation.

Comment: @HotLicks - Me too!

Comment: Hey, I'm married to a Norwegian -- that hardly counts!!  (What?  You say it's "misNEGation"??  Never mind...)

Comment: @HotLicks hahahahaha good one!

Answer (score 2):

No, definitely not. Lawyers do not like to say 'no possible case', since there is practically no limit to what an ingenious plaintiff can base a complaint on. You can, however, say that any such complaint would be adjudged frivolous.

If somebody says to you "Do not use unnecessary words", do you worry about whether the intended meaning was "do not use necessary words"?

Comment: @claumd Note, however, that this is not professional lawyer-speak. A Real Lawyer would write "You do not have any non-frivolous **case** for defamation against &c".

Comment: I agree with you!

Answer (score 1):

My reading of the quoted language—

> Having reviewed the posts that you have identified, I conclude that you do not have any non-frivolous defamation against any of the posters.

is that it is intended as a short form of this language:

> Having reviewed the posts that you have identified, I conclude that you do not have **legal grounds to pursue** any non-frivolous **action for** defamation against any of the posters.

In other words, you can pursue an action for defamation in court, but any sensible judge will conclude that your action is frivolous—that is, according to definition 1b of *frivolous* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003), "having no sound basis (as in fact or law)."

So the lawyer (or pseudo-lawyer) is telling the client (or pseudo-client) that any proposed action for defamation based on the specified online posts is without merit and will fail in court.

Answer (score 0):

In legal land, *frivolous* stuff is *not valid*. So *non-frivolous* stuff is *valid*.

So *... you do not have any **non-frivolous** ...* means *... you do not have any **valid** ...*

In context, *... you do not have any valid defamation [claims] against ...*

In legal parlance, *your screwed*.